# How can I convert values coming from canvas onTouchEvent() into opengl coordinate values?

Tags: android, canvas, opengl-es

I have a custom view and draw an image on the custom view. And I placed a `GLSurfaceView` on top of my custom view and rendered the same image.

Now what I want to achieve is to draw on the `GLSurfaceView` when a use touches the custom view. Since the coordinate systems of the canvas and OpenGL are different the input coordinates have to be transformed.

How can I transform the values coming from the canvas `onTouchEvent()` to the `GLSurfaceView` to render.

Comment: I reformulated you question. Could you please check if I got it right?

Comment: you should use `int x = (int) event.getX(); int y = (int) event.getY();`. But convert this absolute values in relative values (percent of touched views width(x) height(y))

Comment: Sorry I didn't get it as i am beginner to android development and opengl could you please provide me some code.